# What should I build to distribute daily work from an export

Tags: excel, ms-access, sharepoint, office365, microsoft-dynamics

Right now I export a large amount of data from a legacy system into CSV, then use excel macros to automatically filter and split up daily "inventory" for 20+ users to work. I've attempted uploading the CSV into access but it's too slow and ends up much larger than I want it to be.

I have all of the same data into a SQL server already. Normally I would set up my own web service and toss together a quick site. However I'm limited to Azure and office online products. I was wondering what Microsoft online product would be better to make dashboards for the users and distribute the work. I guess just need to know if I should focus on learning SharePoint online or Dynamics online or if MS has another product that would be a better fit.

Comment: It might help if we had a better idea of what the current macros are doing to be able to determine what the actual requirements are. Azure has a wide variety of tools available, including Azure App Service if you want to build something custom and host it within Azure. Microsoft's Power BI is also good for many types of dashboards.

Comment: So the macors filter out the rows for different reasons in several columns. The VBA basically narrows the "inventory" to what needs to be looked at or double checked by a human. Then the VBA makes new sheets per user and chops up the inventory and copies it to the different user sheets. When it's all done it splits off the sheets into new workbooks and a manager emails the xls to everyone. I want can do all the SQL queries to get the Inventory narrowed where I need it. Then break it down and have different pools that I can assign users to and have it in a dash board.

Comment: As they work the inventory, they'll grab the  next record in which ever pool they are in. So one of the MS online products will display records a nice dashboard and work well with SQL.

Comment: Maybe look at what Power BI can do. It works well with SQL and you can add custom SQL or manipulate the queries you use to load the data into it. It's pretty straight forward to use, so that's where I'd start, then move to something else if that doesn't get you what you need. You could also look at using stored procedures directly in SQL to perform the filtering and split it into separate tables instead of the current method of using new sheets in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and getting pointed in a direction. I'll start there.